# PNG Image losing quality when used in UIImageView in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview

I've been banging my head all day and wasn't able to find an answer that worked for me.

I've made some custom button designs in `Sketch`, but when I put them in Assets (with @2x and @3x) and put it in `UIImageView`, the PNG image looses quality:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

The image as saved from Sketch :

*The image is a bit different as I've tried to save it and scale it since I took the screenshot of the storyboard's image.

[image]

Comment: Did you take that screenshot from the storyboard or from a simulator?

Comment: @Sweeper In storyboard, but the png in simulator looks the same.

Comment: the problem goes on because sometimes they sent you wrong image sizes

Comment: @TanjimaKothiya can you please elaborate?

Comment: https://itopstory.com/how-to-use-retini-to-generate-2x-1x-from-3x-en-a1b448c9959 refer this link @VadimF.

Comment: Is the PNG saved in a 8-bit or 24-bit format?

Comment: @JeshuaLacock It says it's color profile is sRGB, which is 8bit if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Can you post the image somewhere so we can take a look at it?

Comment: @JeshuaLacock I've edited the post with the image from Sketch

Comment: It looks like the image is being scaled using nearest neighbor interpolation or something. Are you using any code on the UIImage, or is it all done with Storyboard?

Comment: Can you let me know the size of control where you are setting this image?

Comment: @JeshuaLacock all in storyboard

Comment: @VadimF. -- when you say *"...  button designs in Sketch, but when I put them in Assets ..."* do you mean you **export** them from Sketch as .png files, and add those to Assets? If so, edit your question and post the actual .png file(s) that you are using -- not screen caps or *"tried to save it and scale it"* versions.